# write different grouped rdd values to one file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop2

I have a `groupedRDD` which is of type `key = String` and `value = Iterable<String>`

Value is actually holding the `json` data in `String` format and the grouping keys are in the format of `<tenant_id>/<year>/<month>`

I want to save this rdd to hdfs based on the key name and each key name should have only one output file

Example: If I have the following keys in my grouped rdd

```
tenant1/2016/12/output_data.json
tenant1/2017/01/output_data.json
tenant1/2017/02/output_data.json
```

Then in my HDFS I should have three files

```
tenant1/2016/12/output_data.json
tenant1/2017/01/output_data.json
tenant1/2017/02/output_data.json
```

To do this I have tried the below:

```
class RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
  override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = NullWritable.get()
  override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = key.asInstanceOf[String]
}

groupedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(1))
    .saveAsHadoopFile("/user/pkhode/output/", classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat])
```

This gives the number of output files as expected

```
/user/pkhode/output/tenant1/2016/12/output_data.json
/user/pkhode/output/tenant1/2017/01/output_data.json
/user/pkhode/output/tenant1/2017/02/output_data.json
```

But the data in these files should be each string which is of type json data in one row. But the outcome is some thing like this

```
List({json_object_in_string1}, {json_object_in_string2}, .....)
```

The expected result is

```
{json_object_in_string1}
{json_object_in_string2}
.....
```

some one can point me, how can I achieve this?

### Update:

Thanks to @Tim P, I have updated my code to following

```
groupedRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(1000)).mapValues(_.mkString("\n")).saveAsHadoopFile(outputPath, classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RDDMultipleTextOutputFormat])
```

this solution is working fine as expected for smaller size of data, but when I try the same with around 20GB input dataset, its giving me following error during `mapValue` stage

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:181)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:160)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString_slow(Output.java:462)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString(Output.java:363)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:191)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:184)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
    at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer$$anonfun$write$1.apply(Traversable.scala:29)
    at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer$$anonfun$write$1.apply(Traversable.scala:27)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer.write(Traversable.scala:27)
    at com.twitter.chill.TraversableSerializer.write(Traversable.scala:21)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeValue(Serializer.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.insertRecordIntoSorter(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:164)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `RDD` I have converted my RDD to `PairedRDD` something like below:

```
val resultRDD = inputRDD.map(row => {
  val gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls.create
  val data = gson.toJson(row)
  val fileURL = s"${row.getTenantId}/${row.getYear}/${row.getMonth}/output_data.json"

  (fileURL, data)
})
```

then called `saveAsHadoopFile` to save the outcome to individual files like below:

```
class RddMultiTextOutputFormat extends MultipleTextOutputFormat[Any, Any] {
  override def generateActualKey(key: Any, value: Any): Any = NullWritable.get()
  override def generateFileNameForKeyValue(key: Any, value: Any, name: String): String = key.asInstanceOf[String]
}

resultRDD.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(1000)).saveAsHadoopFile(outputPath, classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[RddMultiTextOutputFormat])
```

Answer (score 0):

When Spark saves an RDD as a text file, it just calls `toString` on the RDD elements.  Try mapping the value to a `String` first:

```
rdd.mapValues(_.mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: thanks Tim, this works for smaller set, but when I run with bigger dataset its giving me exception, updated the same in my question